# Apply map using a different function to each element of the list

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I currently have this bit of code:

```
function string keys = map (xor 1) (map ord string)
```

Which takes every element from the string and xor's it with 1.
I would like to make the map function more advanced, by replacing 1 with any element from keys.

So for example if `string == "Test"` and `keys = [1,3,6,9]` I would get:

```
'T' xor 1
'e' xor 3
's' xor 6
't' xor 9
```

Is there a way to iterate over all element of keys so that I can achieve this? I'm pretty new to Haskell and I don't have a good grasp of its concepts.

My attempt at solving this was:

```
function string keys = map (iterate xor keys) (map ord string)
```

but I got a few errors and I guess it's because of the iterate function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Just as I posted I noticed that iterate does a completely different thing so at this point I know why it doesn't work but I don't know how to replace it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to associate one element of a list with one element of the other list.
This is often called *zipping*. The [`zipWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) seems to do exactly what you want:

```
Prelude Data.Bits> zipWith xor [1, 3, 5] [10, 23, 44]
[11,20,41]
```

It takes an `a -> b -> c` function, an `[a]` list and a `[b]` list and apply the function element wise with corresponding elements from the two lists.

It is a generalization of the `zip` function that produces pairs of element (`zip = zipWith (,)`).

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for! Is there a good place where I can find similar functions that I could study? Not necessarily functions that do the same thing, but useful ones for beginners.

Comment: @Xzenon You can use [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to find functions by name or type . For example in your case you wanted something with type `(a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]`, searching for thing produces [these results](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+a+-%3E+a%29+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+[a]) and you can see `zipWith` too among them. Also you should check the `Prelude` module to see the most useful functions.

Answer (score 0):

That's what the `ZipList` instance of type class [`Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html) is doing:

```hs
 > getZipList $ xor      . ord <$> ZipList "Test" <*> ZipList [1,3,6,9, 11]
[85,102,117,125]
```

The `get/ZipList`s serve as kind of markers to signal our intent to zip, instead of the regular list's cross-product behaviour. We're supposed to pretend--"ignore" them, reading it in our minds instead as

```hs
-- zipWith   ( xor       . ord )           "Test"             [1,3,6,9, 11]
```

which is the same as

```hs
-- zipWith     xor (map    ord             "Test" )           [1,3,6,9, 11]
-- zipWith ($) (map (xor . ord)            "Test" )           [1,3,6,9, 11]
-- map (uncurry ($)) (zip (map (xor . ord) "Test" )           [1,3,6,9, 11] )
-- map (\(a,b)-> xor (ord a) b) (zip       "Test"             [1,3,6,9, 11] )
```

`<$>` is a synonym for `fmap` which is a synonym for `map`, and `<*>` is "apply".

Without the `ZipList` marker, we get

```hs
 >    [ord] <*> "Test"
[84,101,115,116]

--     ord  <$> "Test"
-- map ord      "Test"
```

Specifically, your code should be tweaked a little bit into

```hs
function :: [Char] -> [Int] -> [Int]
-- function string keys = map (iterate xor keys) (map ord string)
function string keys = zipWith ($) (map xor keys) (map ord string)
      -- = getZipList $ (xor <$> ZipList keys) <*> (ord <$> ZipList string)
```

`($)` is an application operator, `($) f x = f $ x = f x`.